# Error while importing geotiff file into postgresql database in linux platform

Tags: gdal, postgresql, postgis-2.0, linux, postgis-raster

I am trying to import GeoTIFF file into spatially enabled PostgreSQL database.
Using command:

```
 raster2pgsql -s 4326 -C -F -a path/to/geotiff/file public.table_name 
 | psql -d database_name -U postgres.
```

This commands is working absolutely fine in Windows (Postgres 9.1), but it is giving an error in linux (Redhat 7.2, Postgres 9.1/Postgres9.5).
It gives the following error:

> rt_raster_gdal_warp: could not create GDAL transformation object for output dataset creation
>   context: SQL function "ST_transform" statement 1.

I have also tried setting PROJSO and PROJ_LIB environment variable with

> export PROJSO=/path/to/ibproj.so

but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the same issue has been faced by us few time back.
Basically the isssue is with version mismatch.
It is advisable that u shd check with higher version of GDAL  GREATER THAN 1.11.1 specificaly on LINUX (RHEL or CENTOS) flavor.
Once ur done with the installation a reboot is mandatory.
Do not forgot to set GDAL_DATA, PROJSO env variable.

Comment: It solved my problem.

Comment: Philip:  I'm having the same issue and am wondering if you can expand on your fix a bit?  Did you roll back your gdal and proj?